# Move About as separate class

Tags: android

I'm wasting a lot of time trying to write this:

```
private void showAbout() {
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Generator.this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.about);
    dialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.about));
    dialog.setCancelable(true);

    try {
        TextView tv_version = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_version);
        tv_version.setText("Version number: " + getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
            getPackageName(), 0).versionName);
        TextView tv_createdBy = (TextView) dialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.tv_createdBy);
            tv_createdBy.setText(getString(R.string.made_by));
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "showAbout()", e);
        } finally {
            dialog.show();
        }
}
```

Over to a class in hope to make my code more readable.

I have written it like this:

```
    private void showAbout() {
                About about = new About();
                about.show();
}

public class About extends Activity {
    String TAG = "About";
    Dialog dialog;

    /**
     * 
     */
    public About() {
        dialog = new Dialog(About.this);

    }

    public void show() {

        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.about);
        dialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.about));
        dialog.setCancelable(true);

        try {
            TextView tv_version = (TextView) dialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.tv_version);
            tv_version
                    .setText("Version number: "
                            + getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                                    getPackageName(), 0).versionName);
            TextView tv_createdBy = (TextView) dialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.tv_createdBy);
            tv_createdBy.setText(getString(R.string.made_by));
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "showAbout()", e);
        } finally {
            dialog.show();

        }
    }

}
```

Bt it doesn't work. It seems like it crashes at the creation of the Dialog, but I have no idea how to write it in another way.

Any ideas?

Comment: how do you call the activity? have you define the activity in androidmanifest.xml?

Comment: It's a good point. How do you have an idea on how I should define the activity? I'm not really good at this - yet.

Comment: how do you want to display the `about`? in popup dialog? or in another activity?

Comment: In a pop-up. It's the exact same prinsiple as in the function showAbout() - I was just hoping to tidy up the code for readability, and as well have a class I can reuse in other programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the fact that you want to display about in a `pop-up` way. Then you're doing it wrong. Extending class to Activity will make it an Activity Class (to be used in activity). You should do something like this:

```
//class level variable
private Dialog formDialog = null;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    prepareDialog();
}

/**
 * We prepare dialog in it's own method so that we can maintain code separation well.
 * I believe there is another <em>better</em> solution. But, it work for now.
 */
private void prepareDialog() {
    formDialog = new Dialog(ListDataActivity.this);
    formDialog.setContentView(R.layout.form);
    formDialog.setTitle("Form Buku");

    // set dialog width to fill_parent
    LayoutParams formDialogParams = formDialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
    formDialogParams.width = LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
    formDialog.getWindow().setAttributes(
            (android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams) formDialogParams);

    txtNama = (EditText) formDialog.findViewById(R.id.txtFormNamaPenulis);
    txtNama.setText( "about info" );


    btnSimpan = (Button) formDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnFormSimpan);

    btnBack.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            formDialog.hide();
        }
    });
}
```

Note that you will also need to create new .xml layout for this dialog.

Finally, all you have to do to display it is just call `formDialog.show();`. This answer is extracted and slightly modified from my [android tutorial](https://github.com/ariefbayu/android-list-form-db).

Answer (score 0):

Every example I've seen about extending `Activity` class includes overriding the `onCreate`method. Therefore, you should add the `onCreate` method and call it's super method by `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

I also think that a dialog showing should not be an activity. Dialog is always a part of activity.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the code to create and show the "about" dialog in a base `Activity`, then have your other `Activites` extend the base one.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. In general do ou think i shoud just drop it because it's just a bad idea?